# Todos os elementos da lista são inseridos na mesma célula num ficheiro csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Queria que a lista `l` fosse inseria no ficheiro csv, ao longo da linha. Ou seja, `l[0]` na primeira célula, `l[1]` na segunda célula...
O que acontece, é que cada lista fica dentro de uma só célula, na primeira coluna.
O `print(l)` apenas serviu para detectar erros.
O `n` é o número de listas, ou seja, o número de linhas.
Espero que me consigam ajudar, sou inexperiente nisto.

```
from numpy import random
import csv

l = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

f = open("funcionarios.csv", 'a', encoding="UTF-8", newline="")
writer = csv.writer(f)

n = int(input("Insira o número de funcionários: "))

for i in range(0, n):
    l[0] = input("Insira o Id. de funcionário: ")
    l[1] = input("Insira o nome do funcionário: ")
    l[2] = input("Insira a data do primeiro contrato (dd.mm.aaaa): ")
    l[4] = random.randint(0, 4)
    l[5] = random.randint(0, 4) 
    l[6] = random.randint(0, 4 - l[5])
    l[3] = l[4] * (l[5] - l[6])
    print(l)
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(l)

f.close()
```

Comment: Eu corri as linhas de código da pergunta (sem fazer qualquer alteração) e não tive problema. O problema não estará depois no programa que está a ler o csv criado?

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que você está abrindo o CSV com algum programa de planilhas como Excel ou LibreOffice Calc certo?

CSV significa "*Comma Separated Values*", ou seja, valores separados por vírgula. Sendo assim, por padrão o módulo "csv" escreve os valores separando eles por vírgula.

Porém, o Brasil utiliza o chamado "padrão europeu" para expressar números decimais, separando-os por vírgula. Isso acaba trazendo problemas quando abrindo um arquivo CSV nestes programas pois o este identifica os separadores de decimais como um delimitador para as colunas dos dados. Assim, o delimitador padrão utilizado no Brasil é o ponto-e-vírgula(;).

Você tem duas opções:

- Alterar a configuração do programa que você está usando para abrir o CSV.
- Usar o parâmetro "delimiter" do método "writer" para que ele escreva o arquivo separando os dados por ponto-e-vírgula(;):

  writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')

Referências:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer
https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.delimiter